# 500 error page not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am setting up a LAMP server and I have an html document set as my 500 error page in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

but if I try to pull up a page with some garbled PHP code, then I just get a 500 error without being served the `500.html` document.

Comment: @anubhava Do you have another method you use to test 500 errors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can trigger 500 error and cause your 500 handler to be invoked:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .foo
```

Then create a file called `abc.foo` under site root with some random text.

Comment: So, I guess that's what I meant by garbled PHP. I added some random text to my `index.php` that I'm using for routing.

Comment: With garbled text you also need this `ExecCGI` option and `AddHandler` to trigger 500

Comment: Well, I'm having no trouble triggering the 500 error with garbled PHP without those two lines and when I add them to the bottom of my `.htaccess` file it causes `index.php` to be downloaded from the browser rather than processed.

Comment: ok check updated answer and make sure to create a file with `.foo` extension and put some garbled text to cause 500 and invoke `ErrorDocument`

Comment: I added those too lines, created `abc.foo` with a random string of text, and opened the file in the browser to find ... that random string of text I typed with status code 200. 

I would just like to reiterate that I have no trouble creating a 500 error by putting garbled PHP in `index.php` and that my problem is getting `500.html` to be served *ALONG WITH* the 500 status code.

Comment: You don't need to reiterate that as I had understood it even before posting the answer. Causing 500 is as simple as `<php? http_response_code(500); ?>` in PHP code. All this is to make use of `ErrorDocument 500` as well.

Comment: I've exact same setup in my Apache and it does both i.e. 1. Gets status `500` to client and 2. Shows `ErrorDocument 500`